# Is there overflow or underflow?

Tags: binary

> Assume 185 and 122 are unsigned 8-bit decimal integers.Calculate 185 – 122. Is there overflow, underflow, or neither?
>
> overflow (floating- point) A situation in which a positive exponent becomes too large to fit in the exponent field.
>
> underflow (floating- point) A situation
>   in which a negative exponent becomes too large to fit in the exponent field.

So 185: 10111001 (binary)
and 122 = 01111010 (binary)

Where do I go form here?

Is this subtraction right?

```
  10111001
 -01111010
  00111111
```

Neither? Is that right?

Another question:

> Assume 185 and 122 are signed 8-bit decimal integers stored in sign-magnitude format. Calculate 185 + 122. Is there overflow, underflow, or neither?

Adding it up:

```
 10111001
+01111010
 100110011
```

So overflow? Is that right?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Yes.

Comment: But 185 is negative becuase it is 10111001 in binary. So I feel like there shouldn't be overflow?

Answer (score 0):

185: 10111001 in binary
122: 01111010 in binary

1. 185 - 122 = 63 = 0b00111111
   => right
2. 185 + 122 = 0b100110011
   => requires 9-bit, overflow will occur.

In the question, both 185 and 122 are 'unsigned 8-bit integer'. You don't need to consider significant bit.